# При использовании -fsanitize=address не работает программа

Tags: c, makefile

Всем доброго времени суток) Пишу игру на С и столкнулся с проблемой. При компиляции проекта без флага -fsanitize=address
все работает но иногда ловлю segmentation fault решил проверить и добавить флаг -fsanitize=address, но с ним сразу же выводится информация о ошибках, убираю флаг все работает как было. Как так получается, и почему программа без флага не видает segmentation fault?

Функция где падает при использовании флага :

```
void    dda_ray(t_data *data)
{
    while (HIT == 0)
    {
        if (SIDE_DIST_X < SIDE_DIST_Y)
        {
            SIDE_DIST_X += DELTA_DIST_X;
            MAP_X += STEP_X;
            SIDE = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            SIDE_DIST_Y += DELTA_DIST_Y;
            MAP_Y += STEP_Y;
            SIDE = 1;
        }
        if (data->array[data->level][MAP_Y][MAP_X] > 0
            && data->array[data->level][MAP_Y][MAP_X] < data->max_box)
            HIT = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Формально: Промахиваться мимо массива - это неопределенное поведение. После него никакое конкретное поведение программы не гарантируется. Соответственно, вылет с segfault'ом тоже не гарантируется.

Comment: Хорошо бы посмотреть вывод санитайзера - обычно по нем довольно просто понять что и почему.

Comment: Могу предположить, что у вас проблема в глобальных переменных - они на каком-то этапе получают значение большее, нежели размеры вашего массива. Тем более, что вы нигде не проверяете их, а сразу обращаетесь по адресу - Вы прям напрашиваетесь) не вылетает сразу либо потому, что у вас на стэке перед этим массивом был выделен достаточный участок памяти (и при выходе за пределы массива, выход за пределы стэка не происходит), либо проблема сужается и у вас превышение по y-кам.

Comment: Посоветую не использовать глобальные переменные - есть много причин почему это плохо, от непонятного кода, до проблем в многопоточности. Но если вам прям необходимо - создайте в вашей функции static переменную. Так она будет хранится не на стэке функции, но будет из нее доступна (а из других мест - нет, по крайней мере если не знать где искать).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Спасибо, не знал этого, действительно мимо  массива попадал(

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Глобальные переменные не использую(если често никогда и не приходилось их использовать ), проблема была в массиве

Comment: @Vadim тогда что такое: SIDE_DIST_X и другие? Это не дефайны  (хотя написаны в верхнем регистре), не константы и доступны в функции без объявления... Если это не глобальные переменные, тогда что это такое?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch это дефайны, выглядят примерно так :
# define SIDE_DIST_X data->raycast.side_dist_x

Comment: @Vadim а какая причина вообще так делать? Этот дэфайн больше никуда и не вставить (иначе ошибка компиляции, имя переменной не изменить, саму переменную тоже не переопределить, а в коде, не зная какой это дэфайн, никогда не поймешь что это не глобальная переменная, а такой вот дефайн...

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch ну я его и в других функциях использую,(главная проблема почему я его использовал не техническая)дело в том что это проект который я делаю в своем учебном заведении есть свои нормы для написания кода на си иначе система не пропустит проект (к-тво сим, в строке и т.д) и я решил сделать так что бы не разбивать 1 функцию на 2/

Comment: @Vadim если и используете, то только за счет одинаковых имен переменной. И не понял зачем разбивать одну функцию на две? Дэфайн - это просто способ вставить определенные символы, на место вашего дефайна, силами препроцессора. Это никак не может повлиять не то что на функцию, а даже на количество строк кода (так как они могут быть только однострочными). Что же касается количества символов в строке - есть только одно разумное требование на сей счет: не более 80 символов, включая пробелы. Но и это требование говорит только о форматировании, но никак не о каком-то лимите.